# Fazer uma variável de referência apontar para outra variável

Tags: c++, variáveis, referência

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, por exemplo:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

int & r = a;
```

Como faço para a variável de referência `r` apontar para `b` e não mais para `a`? É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Como a variável é uma referência e este tipo é imutável, não tem como fazer desta forma. Com um ponteiro é possível obter o mesmo resultado. Após criar um ponteiro para `a`, é possível apontar para outros endereços. Note que no caso de ponteiro tem que atribuir um endereço de forma direta, então você não pode atribuir à variável, tem que usar o operador `&` para pegar o endereço dela.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int *r = &a;
    cout << *r << endl;
    r = &b;
    cout << *r << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/SpXnth). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sigabcwx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/ReferenceBidirecional.cpp).

Comment: Quando você faz `r = b` você está apenas atribuindo a `r` o valor de `b`. Se você ler a variável `a` vai ver que ela também foi alterada, pois a referência aponta para ela.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser Tem razão. Eu comecei respondendo assim e depois fiz o teste ingênuo e vi que "dava" para fazer desta forma. Já estava com sono :) Agora o seu está errado porque não pode usar o ponteiro na atribuição simples da variável.

Comment: Verdade, a gente faz esses exemplos de cabeça e sempre escapa alguma coisinha. Valeu.

Answer (score 2):

Isto não é possível. Uma vez que uma referência é inicializada ela fica atrelada àquela variável até o final de sua vida. Tanto é que você não pode criar uma referência sem inicializálá:

```
int & r; //Erro de compilação
```

Para fazer o que você quer você deve utilizar ponteiros:

```
int a = 5; int b = 10;

int * r = &a; //r aponta para a

std::cout << *r << std::endl; //Imprime 5

r = &b; //r agora aponta para b
*r = 8; //altera o valor de b através de r

std::cout << b << std::endl; //Imprime 8
```